# Measure still returning negative in sum even with bigint

Tags: t-sql, ssas, sql-server-data-tools

I was browsing the cube and noticed that we have a measure `Period` that was returning negative values on a `sum`. In SSMS, I changed the column to `bigint`, refreshed the `SSDT DSV` and it recognized the change.

I processed the cube and noticed that I was still getting the negative value for one group.
I checked the column in the DSV and it says `System.Int64` (not bigint):

[image].

On the other hand, if I check the DSV XML, the datatype is set to `xs:long` (not `bigint` or `System.Int64`):

`<xs:element name="period" msprop:DbColumnName="period" msprop:FriendlyName="period" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0" />`.

The odd thing is that this happens with just one measure that is particularly high. Two of the measures are 10 digits (Florida and California) with 1001769300 and 3296682000 respectively, but California is being converted to negative in the cube.

Two questions:

1. If I set `FactTable.Period` to `bigint` in the database, why is SSDT setting it to `System.Int64` in the DSV GUI and `xs:long` in the XML DSV?
2. How can I fix the issue?

[image]

Comment: A `BIGINT` is a 64-bit signed integer, so negative numbers are possible

Comment: The limit for `bigint` is 2^63-1. The total of _3296682000_ is smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the actual Measure handn't been updated, even though it was updated in the DSV:
[image]

I changed it to `bigint` and the issue was fixed.

I'm still not sure why the DSV, the XML DSV, the cube measure, and the actual SQL table all display different `datatypes`.